# Continue working on a Git branch after making a pull request

Tags: git, version-control, github

I've found myself in this situation a couple of times lately, and I'm not totally sure how best to handle it.

So I have a fork of a git repository that I'm contributing to. I keep my master branch synced with the upstream master branch.

When I want to work on a new feature, bugfix, etc, I create a branch from my master and do any work. When I'm done, I merge in any changes that have been made to upstream master in the meantime, and then send a pull request from my feature/bugfix branch to the upstream master.

Now, while I'm waiting for that pull request to be accepted, I want to work on something slightly different. However, the new feature work needs the bugfix/new feature that I just sent the pull request for. I need to build on it.

How do I branch/merge/handle branches in such a way that I can work on the continuation, while still being able to merge/pull request in my changes in a clean way once the first pull request is accepted into master?

This is all using Github, although I imagine the answer would be applicable to Git in general.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Create a new branch *feature2* based on the last commit to *feature1*. *feature1* will not move forward any more, and can be merged.

*feature2* can then be merged later (some people would argue to rebase *feature2* on the commit where *feature1* was merged into upstream, but personally i dislike rebasing).

Comment: So if feature 1 is merged into master, there won't be conflict issues if I later merge feature 2 (based on feature 1) into master?

Comment: @IsaacDontjeLindell the fact that feature2 is based on feature1 will not introduce extra conflicts, no. there can be conflicts of course, but they would be unrelated to the fact that it is based on feature1. also, if feature1 gets rejected, merging feature2 would pull it in again, unless you rebase feature2 first.

Comment: @IsaacDontjeLindell tip: you can try all this with a local clone that you delete after the experiment.

Comment: @mnagel What if feature 1 is rejected and needs some slight changes?  The changes are added to feature 1.  Then I guess those commits need to be merged into feature 2 before feature 2 is complete and ready for merging into master?  And feature 1 would always need to be merged into master before feature 2?

Comment: This is what I've been doing (using Git TFS). Only downside I've noticed from this approach is that the pull requests are relative to master, so the `Feature2` pull request diff will show changes from `Feature1` as well, which bloats the pull request and hides the distinction between Feature1 and Feature2 changes.

Comment: @Sam that should be avoidable by rebasing feature2 onto the merge commit of feature1/master

Comment: @mnagel this is true, the case I was referring is if you finish Feature2 development before the Feature1 pull request is completed. In this scenario you'd have another pull request for Feature2 relative to master, which would show every change from Feature1 as well.

Comment: what If feature 2 is based on feature1 at the same time?

Answer (score 6):

Given the prevalence of this workflow and the traps along the way, I think guidance is lacking. In particular, the OP mentions GitHub, yet there is little to be found on what happens when you click "Update with rebase" or "Update with merge commit" buttons that are commonly presented in this workflow.

For extra clarity, here's one way to proceed that ought to be illustrative. First the setup:

```bash
$ git pull # on master branch, will update master branch
$ git switch -c feature1 # create new branch *from master*. Note `switch -c` is the less ambiguous form of `checkout -b` since Git 2.23
$ # work on feature 1
$ git add . && git commit -am "commit1"
$ # more work on feature 1
$ git add . && git commit -am "commit2"
$ git push # pushes "feature1" branch with "commit1" and "commit2", from which you can make a Pull Request to be merged with master.
```

And now the OP's predicament - master does not yet contain `feature1`, so how to work on `feature2` that depends on it? Just branch **from the current branch**:

```bash
$ git switch -c feature2 # create new branch *from feature1*.
$ # work on feature 2
$ git add . && git commit -am "commit3"
$ # more work on feature 2
$ git add . && git commit -am "commit4"
```

And at this point there's nothing stopping you `push`ing the new branch. It will *only* contain `commit3` and `commit4`. You can even create a Pull Request to merge it into master. However, [by default](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#require-status-checks-before-merging) GitHub will prevent you from initiating the merge because it detects the branch is "out of date" with master.

So at this point lets assume the remote master is up to date. `feature1` has been merged, and perhaps other, inconsequential commits have been added. We just need to update our own branch. We can do all that from the comfort of our current `feature2` branch:

```bash
$ git rebase master # or `git merge master`, pick your poison
```

Now our `feature2` branch is "up-to-date" as far as GitHub is concerned, but we need to push so it knows about it. **But** if your preferred poison is of the `rebase` kind, remember that your commits have been replayed on top of the new base, so as far as the remote is concerned, they're different commits. So, to avoid things going really pear shaped, **do not** issue a `git pull` at this point, despite the well meaning advice from the command line. Instead, do:

```bash
$ git push --force-with-lease # safer version of --force. Not necessary if you merged instead of rebased.
```

And voila, your Pull Request will now be "up to date" with master and the merge can commence. Plus, we know the (not so mysterious now) magic behind the GitHub buttons:

- "**Update with rebase**" is equivalent to being on the PR branch and issuing `git rebase master` followed by `git push --force-with-lease`.
- "**Update with merge commit**" is equivalent to being on the PR branch and issuing `git merge master` followed by `git push`.